# How to create a dropdown menu as Kickstarter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, width

I'm trying to create a dropdown similar to kickstarter. Here are 2 pictures :

[image]

[image]

But here is what I get instead :

[image]

[image]

It seems like when I click on "Mon compte" and the dropdown menus appear, the width of the button "Mon compte" automatically change for the same width as the dropdown menu.

I'm trying to keep the same width of the button "Mon compte" before and after. I have been looking for a long period, but I didn't found a solution.

Here is the CSS code followed by my HTML code :

```css
.head_myadds{
color: rgba(180,180,180,1);
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;

}

.head_account{
color: rgba(180,180,180,1);
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
}

.head_sign2{
position: relative;
top: -24px;
left: 15%;
padding-left: 10px;
border-left: 1px solid rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.3);
height: 66px;
}

.head_sign3{
position: relative;
top: -24px;
left: 15%;
padding-right: 0px;

}

.icon_myaccount{
position: relative;
left: 5px;
bottom: 2px;
}

.button_account{
margin: 0px;
min-width: 0px;
padding: 3px 5px 3px 0;
}


.dropdown_account{
position:relative;
bottom: 0px;
width: 350px;
margin: 0px;
min-width: 0px;


}
```

```html
    <div class="header-dropdown-buttons hidden-xs ">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="head_sign2"><a href="#"><span class="head_myadds">Mes annonces</span></a></li>
        <li class="head_sign3"><a class="btn dropdown-toggle button_account" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="head_account">Mon compte   <i class="fa fa-sort-desc pr-10 icon_myaccount"></i></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown_account">
                <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Choice..</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- header dropdown buttons end-->

</div>
```

NOTE : I'm using bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your custom styling is causing the dropdown menu to change the way the navbar list-item is displayed.  Specifically, if you choose not to set the `bottom` and `position` styles in the `.dropdown_account` class then the elements will display as expected.

```
.dropdown_account{
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0px;
    min-width: 0px;
```

If you *must* set the `position` style, set it to `position: absolute`, which is what the Bootstrap `.dropdown-menu` class tries to set it to.  Good luck!